# jQuery if select option val is not equal to

Tags: jquery

I've got a select list which is attached to some anchors lower down the page. That all works fine. However it triggers on the first list item which I don't want. Even though it's unlikely someone will go back to the first option, I'd like to remove any errors from the console.

```
<select name="select-product" id="select-dropdown">
    <option value="nothingselected">Select summit fool</option>
    <option value="#p-1">Something here</option>
    <option value="#p-2">Something here</option>
    <option value="#p-3">Something here</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-dropdown').change( function () {

        var targetPosition = $($(this).val()).offset().top;

        if ($(this).val() =! "nothingselected"){

            console.log("not equal to select a product");

            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetPosition}, 'slow');

            if ($('html,body').scrollTop() == 0){
                $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
                console.log("reset");    
            }

        }
    });
});
```

However for the if statement where I'm trying to do something like... If this value is NOT equal to this, then do this. I get an error of:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

I've got a feeling it's to do with my use of `.val()` maybe? Would love to solve this with some help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).val() != "nothingselected")
```

your not equal to is ill formed, try the above

Comment: Thank you, didn't spot that :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following instead:

```
if ($(this).val() != "nothingselected"){
```